# Mount a Camcorder on my Hat?

Tags: camcorder, action-cam

Aside from just gluing (or velcroing) the camcorder onto a baseball hat beak, is there something better? Would this type of thing work?

[http://www.amazon.com/Calumet-Quick-release-Video-Head-Adapter/dp/B003LRWB3S/ref=sr_1_102?s=photo&ie=UTF8&qid=1347397880&sr=1-102](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LRWB3S)

or is it irrelevant. If your answer is "get an Go Pro" or whatever, I still need to know how to mount it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to remember about mounting any camera is stability. What makes Go Pro so attractive to many cinematographers are the many mounts available for it that fit the camera snugly on a helmet, car, surf board, or what have you. There will always be some motion when attaching a camera to say a helmet, but with the Go Pro helmet mount, you have minimized any residual motion. The only motion that is left is that of the helmet moving.

Trying to mount a camera to a baseball hat and expecting the stability of a helmet mount Go Pro or Contour camera is not easy or trivial.

First of all a baseball cap is not rigid like a helmet, there is flex built into the cap even in the beak. Adding an adapter may make things worse. You will have to experiment. Consider ways to make the cap as rigid as a helmet and ways to attach the camera so it moves with the cap without any swaying or extra movement.

For every design you think will work you will need to make test shots that cover the conditions of the actual production.

I think this can be done. But without your camera or your cap in my hands I would not venture a guess on how you go about it. This is truly hands on experimental kludge-0-matic work.

Comment: Thanks for this, great answer and +1. Just FYI if it makes a difference, the initial intention is to create videos of iPad demos and so forth. While it's hardly essential to get the thing on my head, the advantage is that I can vary the subject and not have to think about it. Anyway, the point is that some OIS should be enough, I think, for my use case.

Comment: You're very welcome, hope this works out for you.

Comment: Yep, just did some initial tests with velcro: I'm going to need to get my friends who make costumes and stuff like that to help out. I should've paid attention in Arts and Crafts in elementary school!

Answer (score 2):

I've got a GoPro and filzilla is right, stability can be an issue.  There is the [head strap mount](http://gopro.com/camera-mounts/head-strap-mount/) that will fit on your head, or helmet, or even hat, and it works well.  The [chest mount](http://gopro.com/camera-mounts/chest-mount-harness/) works a bit better, more stable and it doesn't move around with your head (much easier to watch).  I'm sure you could get it to work decently with the chest mount.  You may find that, in this case, [using it on a tripod](http://gopro.com/camera-mounts/tripod-mount/) or Gorillapod would be better for stability.

I still like the GoPro for the flexibility it gives, despite the stability issues, it's just good to have it in the bag.